# How to decode JSON file created with GSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, encoding, character-encoding, gson

I've successfully created a JSON file with gson but now that I want to parse that same file, the encoding gets all messed up.

This is the code I use to read the JSON file:

```
BufferedReader jsonFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.json"));
Map<String, List<long[]>> trafficInput = new HashMap<>();
trafficInput = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, HashMap.class);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to ensure the file gets parsed the right way.

For instance, this valid JSON code from the file:

```
{"paris":[[1485907200000,182184411,41274],[1485993600000,151646118,36697],"london":[[1485907200000,30200160,155827]}
```

...gets parsed like this:

```
{"paris":[[1.4859072E12,1.82184411E8,41274.0],[1.4859936E12,1.51646118E8,36697.0],"london":[[1.4859072E12,3.020016E7,155827.0]}
```

This messes up the rest of the code as the longs aren't longs anymore.

For instance, if I try to print out a value, like so:

```
System.out.println(trafficInput.get("paris").get(0)[0]);
```

... I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [J
```

Any help?

Comment: That might just be `toString` implementation of `List/long`, have you tried iterating through the list printing individual value?

Comment: I have and there is an error. It says that the List/longs can't be iterated through as longs. However Strings don't work either.

Comment: `System.out.println(trafficInput.get("paris").get(0)[0]));` what does this print?

Comment: Also, could you share the content of file? (at least, one line containing all the details for 'Paris')?

Comment: When trying your printout command, I get the following error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [J"

Comment: try `System.out.println((trafficInput.get("paris").get(0))[0]);`. Anyway, if you could add one line of your json file, that'd be great.

Comment: Still get the same error.

Comment: The code in the example is a copy paste from the JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the following line:

```
trafficInput = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, HashMap.class);
```

This line instructs `gson` to deserialize the string into `HashMap` without specifying any type, and hence, `gson` applies its default conversion mechanism (i.e. converting `Number` into `double` etc). This is why `Sysout` statement results in a `ClassCastException` because that element is not an `array`.

All you need to do is to specify a `TypeToken` while calling `fromJson` method and it will take care of types. e.g.:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, List<long[]>>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, List<long[]>> trafficInput = new HashMap<>();
trafficInput = gson.fromJson("{\"paris\":[[1485907200000,182184411,41274],[1485993600000,151646118,36697]],\"london\":[[1485907200000,30200160,155827]]}", type);
System.out.println(trafficInput);
System.out.println(gson.toJson(trafficInput));
```

The above snippet prints numbers without scientific notation.